# Java NIO FileChannels Track Progress

Tags: java, web, nio, filechannel

I'm trying to download a mp4 file from the web. I'd like to do it async and track the progress so it can be displayed in a progressbar.

My code looks as following:

```
 URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
 ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(con.getInputStream());
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
 fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Would creating a loop with transferFrom only reading up to 32KB each time and incrementing position be good practice, or is there a better way that would enable me to track the progress of the download? And how would I know when to stop transfering?

I just discovered that you can get the file size via the HTTP header field:

```
con.getHeaderFields().get("Content-Length").get(0)
```

Now knowing the filesize should make me able to implement the before mentioned loop.

```
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        long fileSize = Long.parseLong(con.getHeaderFields().get("Content-Length").get(0));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        for (long offset = 0; offset < fileSize; offset += transferBytesAtOnce) {
            in.skip(offset);
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(in);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, offset, transferBytesAtOnce);

            System.out.println(offset + "/" + fileSize);
        }
```

However, as I expected, this solution performs very bad. When keeping the transferBytesAtOnce variable low, it only downloads very slow. When using high values, it cancels the download.

Edit: Nvm, replaced the skip by

```
if (offset > 0) {
                in.skip(transferBytesAtOnce);
            }
```

It's working a bit better now, but still not nearly as fast as the solution which does not track progress.

Comment: Well make up your mind. D you want it fast or do you want to track progress? You only need to track progress if it isn't fast.

Comment: I need to track progress anyway, since I'm talking about a 200 MB file, which won't just load in a second. I was under the impression that the progress tracking was slowing down the download much more than it's actually the case. I'm now using a BufferedInputStream from which I'm reading 4KB  per Loop, which seems to download without slowing it down. However, I can't tell wether the channels solution was slower only in my imagination or in reality.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/IO_How_to/FileChannel/Monitor_progress_of_FileChannels_transferFrom_method.htm) I write this class

```
public class ReadableConsumerByteChannel implements ReadableByteChannel {

    private final ReadableByteChannel rbc;
    private final IntConsumer onRead;

    private int totalByteRead;

    public ReadableConsumerByteChannel(ReadableByteChannel rbc, IntConsumer onBytesRead) {
        this.rbc = rbc;
        this.onRead = onBytesRead;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(ByteBuffer dst) throws IOException {
        int nRead = rbc.read(dst);
        notifyBytesRead(nRead);
        return nRead;
    }

    protected void notifyBytesRead(int nRead){
        if(nRead<=0) {
            return;
        }
        totalByteRead += nRead;
        onRead.accept(totalByteRead);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return rbc.isOpen();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        rbc.close();
    }
}
```

And use it by wrap the old one like this

```
    URLConnection con = new URL(url).openConnection();
    int fileSize = con.getContentLength();
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(con.getInputStream());
    ReadableConsumerByteChannel rcbc = new ReadableConsumerByteChannel(rbc,(b)->{
        System.out.println("Read  "+b +"/"+fileSize);
    });
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rcbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```